# Как положить на картинку opacity?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

Как положить на картинку opacity что бы при zoom opacity не слазил.
Использую такой код для наложений тений:

```
let tintView = UIView()
tintView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.5)
tintView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: imageView.frame.width, 
height: imageView.frame.height)
imageView.addSubview(tintView)
```

и для zoom:

```
@objc func doubleTap(gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if self.productScrollView.zoomScale == 1 {
        self.productScrollView.zoom(to: self.zoomRectForScale(scale: self.productScrollView.maximumZoomScale, center: gestureRecognizer.location(in: gestureRecognizer.view)), animated: true)
    } else {
        self.productScrollView.setZoomScale(1, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Проблема в том что когда я увеличиваю картинку tintView слазит немного вниз.

[image]

Comment: Немного непонятно что именно Вы хотите. Добавить прозрачную UIView поверх UIImageView?

Comment: @VAndrJ именно)

Comment: Можете добавить пример проекта где воспроизводится ошибка?

Answer (score 0):

Не надо задавать frame, apple давно уже рекомендуют не работать с фреймами, а задавать constraints. Например в вашем случае наверное

```
  let tintView = UIView()
  tintView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.5)
  tintView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
  imageView.addSubview(tintView)
  NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            tintView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.bottomAnchor),
            tintView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.leadingAnchor),
            tintView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.trailingAnchor),
            tintView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.topAnchor),
            ])
```

Comment: Не работает, такая же проблема при увеличении и уменьшение tintView обрезаеться.